# How to change the default colors created by groupOTU/groupClade in ggtree

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny, ggtree

When grouping clades by any parameter in a tree file with groupClade or groupOTU, how can one select the colors displayed when plotting?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ggtree(tree, aes(color = group)) +
scale_color_manual(values =c ('#00000', '#AB274F')
```